# Yahoo Blueprint Apps

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

Since yahoo! closed support of all blueprint apps, is there any method to convert existing blueprint custom tags to standard html/x-html code? 
Any information on this regard will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.htm) and [Orbeon Forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms) are based on the same XForms standard as Yahoo Blueprint:

> Much of Blueprint's philosophy and syntax comes from XForms. We opted for a full declarative language because it was the only way we could effectively run on the wide range of devices out there, some of which have no scripting at all. By using declarative syntax, we can encapsulate and hide the scripting specifics. In some cases, the code could run on the phone, in other case, such as XHTML, we can put the logic on our servers. It's the perfect way to deal with the various environments and their capabilities.

Converting Blueprint apps to either of those formats is the simplest solution, since they output HTML.

**References**

- [Developers Are Go: Yahoo! Mobile Developer Platform](http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/yahoo-mobile-developer-platform-022208/)
- [Yahoo Blueprint Platform](http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ydn/openhack/08/blueprint.pdf)
- [Mobile Web Development with Yahoo! Blueprint](http://www.slideshare.net/dreampipe/sea-open-hack-blueprint)